# PowerShell - How to treat an imported column as a set of numeric digits?

Tags: powershell, import, type-conversion

I have a CSV which looks something like:

```
No,BundleNo,Grossweight,Pieces,Tareweight,Netweight
1,Q9,193700,1614,646,193054
2,Q7,206400,1720,688,205712
```

What I want to do is divide each value in the column `Netweight` by 25 but for some reason I am struggling.

Here's what I have code-wise:

```
$fileContent = Import-Csv $file
$netWeight = $fileContent | select Netweight
$netWeight | Foreach-Object { $_/25 }
```

Which gives me an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
```

I have tried several variations attempting to convert the values to a numeric value with no success.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options, the problem is that you're trying to operate on a property of the object.

Using your current version you'd still need to explicitly access the `Netweight` property even though you've already selected it:

```
$netWeight = $fileContent | select Netweight
$netWeight | Foreach-Object { $_.Netweight / 25 }
```

Alternatively, you could flatten the property when you select it:

```
$netWeight = $fileContent | select -ExpandProperty Netweight
$netWeight | Foreach-Object { $_/25 }
```

Comment: I would like to add that with the current setup there is no advantage to the way he's doing it and may as well skip the first line and change the second line to `$FileContent | ForEach{ $_.NetWeight / 25 }`

Comment: Thank you for putting me out of my misery.